# Error with sending Ints/Strings from Python via PySerial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, psutil

I'm trying to build a CPU Monitor with Python and Arduino.
Arduino works fine, but I'm having problems with Python.
My Problem is that I cant get PySerial to send out a int or a string.

If I try to send a Int I get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

If I convert the Int to a string the error is:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

which seems very strange...

Here is my Code:

```
import psutil
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(2)
while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    line = str(line[:-2],'utf-8')
    if line=="cpu":
        cpus = psutil.cpu_times_percent(percpu=True)
        for x in range(4):
            v=int(cpus[x][0]+cpus[x][1])
            print(v)
            ser.write(v)
```

Commenting out the last line confirmes that the values from the CPU are ints between 0 and 100 like expected.

Is this a bug in PySerial or am I just to blind too see a fault?

Answer (score 0):

PySerial indeed accepts strings.
I believe that if you change the last line for the following line it should send data:

```
ser.write(str(v))
```

Comment: I tried that it ouputs: "TypeError: an integer is required"

Comment: Are you sure that the error is for the last line? Put some prints into the last loop or put here the complete error message

Comment: It's in that line Error Code:"                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    ser.write("test")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 283, in write

    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 76, in to_byte
s
    b.append(item)  # this one handles int and str for our emulation and ints fo
r Python 3.x
TypeError: an integer is required"

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by converting str to binary:
    ser.write(str(v).encode())

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The simple solution is as follows:

```
ser.write([v])
```

Now, it can be iterable.

To write strings, you have to convert it bytes.

```
ser.write(b'v')
```